# Consulta en MySQL que recibe como parámetro un año

Tags: mysql, sql

Estoy trabajando con [mysql](/questions/tagged/mysql), y tengo una tabla que guarda reservas que tiene la siguiente estructura:

```
 - Id_reserva
 - Ciudad
 - Estado
 - Fecha_inicio
 - Fecha_fin
```

me he visto en la necesidad de realizar una consulta que me devuelva las reservas recibiendo como parámetro un año, por lo que primeramente generé la siguiente consulta recibiendo como parámetro este año:

```
select *
from reserva r
where YEAR(r.Fecha_inicio) = 2017
```

el problema es que esto me tomara solo los que inician este año, y si tuviera algunos registros que comenzaron el 2016 por ejemplo y terminan recién este año. quiero que también sean incluidos en mi consulta, que debería cambiar o aumentar en mi query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Las respuesta anteriores son parcialmente correctas, pues buscan registros entre 2 fechas, pero se obvia que cuando hablamos de reservas normalmente hablamos de períodos y esto debería ser tenido en cuenta.

Supongamos que una reserva inicia en 2016 y finaliza en 2018, si utilizamos las consultas propuestas:

```
SELECT *
FROM reserva r
WHERE 
    YEAR(r.Fecha_inicio) = 2017 
    OR
    YEAR(r.Fecha_fin) = 2017
```

Este registro no será tenido en cuenta.

¿Que hacemos entonces? Pues incluir tambien aquellas reservas que comiencen antes del año indicado y terminen después del año indicado.

```
SELECT *
FROM reserva r
WHERE 
    (YEAR(r.Fecha_inicio) = 2017 OR YEAR(r.Fecha_fin) = 2017)
    OR
    ( YEAR(r.Fecha_inicio) < 2017 AND YEAR(r.Fecha_fin) > 2017)
```

Es decir en este caso comprobamos:

- si el año de inicio **Ó** fin es igual a 2017
- **Ó** si el año de inicio es menor a 2017 **Y** el año final es mayor a 2017.

Comment: muy buena observacion, voy a probar lo que sugieres en mi consulta.

Comment: Bien visto, pero según dice el OP en la pregunta, él quiere sólo las reservas que finalizan en el año indicado. Si dicho año es `2017`, no le interesan las del año `2018`. Lo que he entendido es que quiere **las reservas que inician o finalizan en un año determinado.**

Answer (score 0):

La consulta sería la siguiente:

```
SELECT *
FROM reserva r
WHERE YEAR(r.Fecha_inicio) = 2017 
    OR YEAR(r.Fecha_fin) = 2017
```

La clave está en el 'OR', con este, el 'WHERE' se lee así; Las reservas que iniciaron en el 2017 **o** finalizaron en el 2017. Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Tendríamos que tomar todos los registros que fecha_inicio =2017 o que tienen como fecha_fin = 2017, esto hará que lo tome por cualquiera de las dos condiciones:

```
SELECT * FROM reserva r
WHERE YEAR(r.fecha_inicio) = 2017 
   OR YEAR(r.fecha_fin) = 2017
```

si no es esto lo que buscas deberías darnos mas detalles de lo que en realidad quieres. 
Saludos.

Comment: Tu solución es la misma a la que planteé, en caso de querer agregar algo mas a mi respuesta pudiste agregar un comentario.